# Combining like data on a spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I'm not sure how I would go about creating a macro (or maybe even an Access query?) for what I'm looking at here. I have a spreadsheet of tens of thousands of customer names/numbers with product data. If a customer has bought two (or more) products, it reflects as multiple entries on the spreadsheet (example below).

```
Name      #      Product
----------------------------
Bob      101    Product 1
Joe      102    Product 3
Bob      101    Product 2
Bob      101    Product 3
Hank     103    Product 2
Susan    104    Product 1
Hank     103    Product 3
```

I want to run something on that spreadsheet that combines the entries into one line, such as the example below. I'm not concerned about how the "products" are delineated... comma, line break, space, whatever. But I would like the end result to look something like this

```
Name      #      Products
-----------------------------------------------
Bob      101    Product 1, Product 2, Product 3
Joe      102    Product 3
Hank     103    Product 2, Product 3
Susan    104    Product 1
```

But I'm not even sure where to start. Any ideas to at least get me in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, it can be sorted. There's 10s of thousands of records though, so anything too manual outside of basic sorting wouldn't be the right way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort on `Product` within `Name` and in D2 (?):

```
=IF(A1=A2,D1&", "&C2,C2)
```

in E2:

```
=A2<>A3.
```

Copy both down, select all, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top, filter to select `FALSE` for ColumnE and delete all visible.

Comment: Awesome. I'll turn that in to a macro and this should be exactly what I'm looking for. Much appreciated.